# Basic Int32 and std_msgs question

Tags: ros, std-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm very new to working in Ros.  I am trying to figure out how to read from a bag file and so I'm interested in making a small bag file for testing purposes.  I have wrapped the code for writing the integer 42 inside a main function and attempted to run it within a catkin package using catkin_make.  I get the following error:

```
[ 81%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/test_write_bag.dir/src/test_write_bag.cpp.o
/home/ryan/catkin_ws/src/test/src/test_write_bag.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/ryan/catkin_ws/src/test/src/test_write_bag.cpp:8:2: error: ‘Int32’ is not a member of ‘std_msgs’
  std_msgs::Int32 i;
  ^
/home/ryan/catkin_ws/src/test/src/test_write_bag.cpp:8:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
  std_msgs::Int32 i;
                  ^
/home/ryan/catkin_ws/src/test/src/test_write_bag.cpp:9:2: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
  i.data = 42;
  ^
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/test_write_bag.dir/src/test_write_bag.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/test_write_bag.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong or forgotten to set up within the project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213657/basic-int32-and-std_msgs-question/) by [The_Mad_Geometer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23167/the_mad_geometer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you `#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>` along with your other headers?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1